# Minimum of a .txt with C++

Tags: c++

I am a real newbie on C++ and want to ask a coding question,

I want to create a C++ code which reads data from a text file, for each K rows, it has to find the minimum value of the array and report it to a separate text file. For example if I have 1000 rows and K is 10 , It has to look for first 100 value and report the minimum, second 100 set and report the second minimum and it goes on...

I have written a code but it isn't work,

Any help will be appreciated,

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open ("High.txt");
if ( !fin ) exit( 1 );
double **a = new double *[N]; 
for ( int i = 0; i < K; i++ ) 
{
   a[i] = new double[N];
}
for ( int i = 0; i < K; i++ )
{
   for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ )
   {
      fin >> a[i][j];
   }
}

double mx[N], mn[N];
int i,j,k; 
for ( i =0; i<N ; i++){
   mn[i] = a[0][i]; 
   mx[i] = a[0][i];
   for ( j = 1; j<K; j++){
      if (mx[i] < a[j][i])
      {mx[i] = a[j][i];}
      if (a[j][i] < mn[i])
      {mn[i] = a[j][i];}
   }
}

ofstream ts("Max.txt", ios::app);
for ( i =0; i<N ; i++){
   ts<<mx[i]<<endl;
}
ts.close();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i make this code work?

Comment: Sorry, N is total number of rows in .txt so, N/K bis size of a single set.

Comment: I assume N is a compile time constant or you have a nonstandard VLA extension since c++ does not have variable length arrays.

Comment: No, code for N is as follows, int num=0; 
ifstream is; 
is.open ("High.txt"); 
while (is.good()) 
{ 
char c; 
c = is.get(); 
if (c=='\n')num++; 
} 
is.close();
int N=num/K;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) to get the minimum values:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("data.txt");
    std::ofstream outfile("min_values.txt");

    const int K = 10;
    std::vector<double> numbers;

    double d;

    while(infile >> d)
    {
        numbers.push_back(d);
    }

    int full_parts = numbers.size() / K;


    for (int i = 0; i < full_parts; i++)
    {
        double min = *std::min_element(numbers.begin() + i * K, numbers.begin() + i * K + K);
        outfile << min << std::endl;
    }

    if (numbers.size() % K != 0)
    {
        double min = *std::min_element(numbers.begin() + full_parts * K, numbers.end());
        outfile << min << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 ifstream fin;
 ofstream fout;
 int i=0,z,K=100,N=1000,x,j;
fout.open("High.txt");

//Generate 1000 positive random numbers below 1000 and print ino High.txt
for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
    fout<<abs(random())%1000;
}
fout.close();

fin.open ("High.txt");
fout.open("out.txt");
if (!fin ) exit( 1 );


while(i<(N/K)){
 z = 1000;
 for(j=0;j<K;j++){ //Reading K line 
        fin>>x;
        z = min(x,z);
 }
 fout<<z<<"\n";
 i++;
}
fout.close();
fin.close();
fin.open("out.txt");
//Print result 
while(!fin.eof()){
    fin>>x;
    cout<<x<<"\n";
}
}
```

//Same code with random number is generated and printed in `High.txt` it prints correct output .Something would we wrong with file opening.

Comment: Thx, but It didn't work. I beleive it is because High.txt contains 1000 rows meanwhile I need to divide it into 1000/K parts and come out with 1000/K minimum values.

Comment: Instead of  z = LARGESET_NUMBER_IN_FILE+1;, I put z=100000, by the way.

Comment: What's problem are u facing ?

Comment: 1  since my data is one number per row.

Comment: Check whether `High.txt` is there in that directory or not ?

Comment: Yes, it is in the directory :)